# NoSuchFieldError: No field TextAppearance_fontFamily of type I

Tags: android, android-studio

I am facing a strange issue while running a project in the android studio, Project has multiple modules in it and launches successfully, but on launching the first activity after the splash screen, it goes into the following error where the Logcat points out this line

```
setContentView(R.layout.activity_layout);
```

Error

```
java.lang.NoSuchFieldError: No field TextAppearance_fontFamily of type I in class Landroid/support/v7/appcompat/R$styleable; or its superclasses (declaration of 'android.support.v7.appcompat.R$styleable' appears in /data/app/PROJECT_PACKAGE_NAME-2/base.apk)
```

A searched a lot but no convincing thing got regarding this issue, most of the time it is said that "you have the layout in both library and module with the same name or inflating multiple XML layouts with duplicate resource id". I have renamed that XML file pointed for error, but couldn't get through it. Thanks for your help.

XML file

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="@drawable/intro_bg">

    <View
        android:id="@+id/top_view"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="54dp"
        android:layout_marginLeft="55dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="55dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="55dp"
        android:alpha="0.8"
        android:background="@drawable/round_corner_mobile_top" />

    <android.support.v4.view.ViewPager
        android:id="@+id/view_pager"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_above="@+id/bottomView"
        android:layout_below="@+id/top_view"
        android:paddingLeft="64dp"
        android:paddingRight="64dp" />

    <View
        android:layout_width="10dp"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_above="@+id/bottomView"
        android:layout_below="@+id/top_view"
        android:layout_marginLeft="55dp"
        android:alpha="0.8"
        android:background="@color/mobile_screen" />

    <View
        android:layout_width="10dp"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_above="@+id/bottomView"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
        android:layout_below="@+id/top_view"
        android:layout_marginRight="55dp"
        android:alpha="0.8"
        android:background="@color/mobile_screen" />

    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/bottomView"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="110dp"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:background="@color/white"
        android:orientation="vertical">

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_gravity="center"
            android:layout_marginTop="15dp">

            <View
                android:id="@+id/circle1"
                android:layout_width="10dp"
                android:layout_height="10dp"
                android:background="@drawable/circle_fill" />

            <View
                android:id="@+id/circle2"
                android:layout_width="10dp"
                android:layout_height="10dp"
                android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
                android:background="@drawable/circle" />

            <View
                android:id="@+id/circle3"
                android:layout_width="10dp"
                android:layout_height="10dp"
                android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
                android:background="@drawable/circle" />

            <View
                android:id="@+id/circle4"
                android:layout_width="10dp"
                android:layout_height="10dp"
                android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
                android:background="@drawable/circle" />
        </LinearLayout>

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginTop="15dp"
            android:orientation="horizontal">

            <LinearLayout
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:background="@drawable/outline_button_yellow"
                android:padding="4dp">

                <Button
                    android:id="@+id/button_sign_up"
                    style="?android:attr/buttonBarButtonStyle"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:background="@drawable/rounded_button_yellow"
                    android:text="@string/signup"
                    android:textColor="@color/white" />

            </LinearLayout>

            <LinearLayout
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:background="@drawable/outline_button_blue"
                android:padding="4dp">


                <Button
                    android:id="@+id/button_sign_in"
                    style="?android:attr/buttonBarButtonStyle"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:background="@drawable/rounded_button_blue"
                    android:text="@string/login"
                    android:textColor="@color/white" />

            </LinearLayout>

            <LinearLayout
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
                android:layout_marginRight="10dp"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:background="@drawable/outline_button_gray"
                android:padding="4dp">

                <Button
                    android:id="@+id/button_skip"
                    style="?android:attr/buttonBarButtonStyle"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:background="@drawable/rounded_button_gray"
                    android:text="@string/skip"
                    android:textColor="@color/white" />
            </LinearLayout>
        </LinearLayout>
    </LinearLayout>
</RelativeLayout>
```

styles.xml

```
<resources>

    <!-- Base application theme. -->
    <style name="AppTheme" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light.DarkActionBar">
        <item name="windowNoTitle">true</item>
        <item name="windowActionBar">false</item>
        <item name="colorPrimary">@color/colorPrimary</item>
        <item name="colorPrimaryDark">@color/colorPrimaryDark</item>
        <item name="colorAccent">@color/colorAccent</item>
        <item name="autoCompleteTextViewStyle">@style/cursorColor</item>
        <item name="android:typeface">serif</item>
    </style>

    <style name="YellowCheck">
        <item name="colorControlNormal">@color/yellow</item>   <!-- normal border color change as you wish -->
        <item name="colorControlActivated">@color/yellow</item>
    </style>

    <style name="cursorColor" parent="Widget.AppCompat.AutoCompleteTextView">
        <item name="android:textCursorDrawable">@drawable/cursor</item>
    </style>

</resources>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You needed to update my SDK tools and SDK platform-tools, select 27 as build target.

Answer (score 0):

First, you need to check the app level build.gradle with all the dependencies in it and also the compile sdk and target sdk.

After doing this, just do a clean build from Build -> Clean build and the project should build without any error.